# Why did Megyn say such words?

Tags: plot-explanation, bombshell

In a scene from *Bombshell* (2019), after playing tennis, Doug warned a Trump supporter who had confronted his wife, Megyn. Then, Megyn spoke to Doug:

> Megyn: You're **getting some action**.
>
> Doug: Oh, really?

This phrase refers to engaging in sexual activity, but the situation doesn’t
seem to involve any sexual activity.

Why did Megyn say such words ?

Comment: Err ... you may want to provide more context here. The phrase "getting some action" CAN mean sexual activity, but it doesn't have to.

Comment: @iandotkelly - And in this case, it's precisely what it means!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [script](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://thescriptlab.com/wp-content/uploads/scripts/2947-Bombshell-by-Charles-Randolph.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjG0rKXmIuEAxUJa0EAHbh2DogQFnoECA8QAQ&usg=AOvVaw1oF-mrC7HEXfwUBtrlsJwZ) makes things a little clearer. Megyn seems threatened by a vocal Trump supporter. Doug steps in and defends her.

Megyn finishes off the interaction by making it clear that his hyper-masculine response (and defensiveness of her) will be [rewarded with sex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+some+action).

> **VICTORIOUS PLAYER** (right in her face):  *Trump ‘16!*
>
> It’s weird and scary.
>
> Doug walks up, having seen the interaction, Megyn’s fear. He hands her his towel, goes to the Man, steps in close.
>
> **DOUG:** (calm) *Talk to my wife again and I’ll beat you to fucking pulp.*
>
> The Player’s Wife’s horrified. Doug nods politely and turns.
>
> As Megyn and Doug clear the court...
>
> **MEGYN:** *Yeah, you’re getting some action.*
>
> INT. BEDROOM - MEGYN’S BEACH HOUSE - JERSEY SHORE - DAY
>
> Megyn and Doug lie naked under the sheets.

Comment: So why on earth did you think this didn't "involve any sexual activity" @JMacBrown? Or does the scene in the movie not end up with them naked in bed?